# Why is there no auxiliary in the question "How many people study there"?

Tags: grammar, questions, auxiliary-verbs

Why don't we use the auxiliary *do* in the following question:

> How many people study there?

Comment: Actually you can: "Most of the people there are not really studying." "Really? How many people *do* study there?"

Comment: @Jeff that's not an auxiliary *do*, that's an emphatic *do*. The sentence is not asking the same thing at all.

Comment: @RegDwightΒВBẞ8 Do tell.

Answer (score 13):

Because *how many people* is the **subject** of the sentence. If you ask a question about the subject, you don't need *do*.

Examples: (subjects are *italicized*)

> *How many people* study here?
>
> *Who* wants chowder?
>
> *Whose child* stole the keys?

Now, if the interrogative pronoun is not (part of) the subject, then we need *do*.

Compare:

> Who did you kill? (who = object)
>
> Who killed you? (who = subject)

Hope this helped.

Comment: So "How many children has your brother?" it's also correct?